# Service not showing can shut down correctly

Tags: powershell

I have an issue where a service is not displaying its 'can shut down' status correctly. Simple code example:

```
for ($counter = 0; $counter -le 5; $counter++) {
    if ((Get-Service -Name BITS).CanShutDown) {
        Write-Output "BITS can shutdown.."    
        break
    }

    else {
        Write-Output "Waiting for service shutdown status.. $counter"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Waiting for service shutdown status.. 0
Waiting for service shutdown status.. 1
Waiting for service shutdown status.. 2
Waiting for service shutdown status.. 3
Waiting for service shutdown status.. 4
Waiting for service shutdown status.. 5
```

If I open a console, and use `Start-Service -Name BITS` while the script is running, the loop does not end.

Why is `CanShutDown` always returning False? Even if BITS is stopped or running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused because `CanShutDown` doesn't quite do what you are expecting.

As [per the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.canshutdown(v=vs.110).aspx),

> ServiceController.CanShutdown
>
> Gets a value indicating whether the
>   service should be notified when the system is shutting down.

Bits doesn't need to be told that system shutdown is about to occur. Other servies, like, say, Sql server do.